# How to disable a Windows 7 license?

Tags: windows-7

I bought my windows from school and installed in my computer. Now I want to upgrade my computer, but I want to keep my Windows 7.

Since there are hardware changes (traditional HD to SSD), I believe MS will detect that I installed it on a different PC.

What should I do in order to disable the Windows on my old PC so that I can use the license key on my new one?

Comment: If it's a completely new PC, make sure the copy of Win7 is not still being used on the old one. In either case (new PC or upgrade of old PC), I suggest you try and activate. If it's a minor hardware change you should have no issues, otherwise call up Microsoft and you should be able to sort it out with no problems whatsoever (probably even without speaking to a live person).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the new SSD and go. It is not enough of a change to cause a re-activation. As well, if you haven't installed a FRESH copy of Windows yet onto your notebook, the key you use underneath the laptop will still work, as it has NEVER been used.

When you buy a laptop or desktop with Windows pre-installed from a big manufacturer (i.e. Acer, HP, Dell, etc), they use a master key that they can activate on thousands of machines all at once. You won't be able to activate that key again, but the key on the physical system (on the sticker) is your OEM key to use if you need to wipe and reload... Or in this case, load up

Comment: Since he got the copy of Win7 from his school (probably via a DreamSpark Premium account) and installed it himself on his PC, I don't think he has an OEM or COA key.

Comment: @karan he's making it sound like he has a second copy to use, including his original one